# SQL Query for SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to create an ssrs report as below --
I have the following columns  to be displayed-

```
                    | Tickets   | Tickets   |
                    | scanned on| scanned on|
Attraction |   Hour | 09/08/2014| 09/09/2014| 09/10/2014| Day 4| Day 5| Day 6| 09/14/2014    
                      Monday       Tuesday     Wednesday ...................... Sunday

U Mueseum  | 9:00 AM |  10      |       40  |
            10:00 aM |
            ..
            ..
            ..
            ..
            ..
            23:00 AM
```

I will get the Start Date and End Date from the user. Now my problem is that I want a query for 7 days starting from the Start Date selected by the user to the End Date and for each hour i.e. for 1 day it would be 24 hrs, so 24*7 hours in total. When I display the value for scans in my current sql query it displays just for one day. How can I do it for 7 days, and the value of scans for that date should be displayed in the respective week day ie. Monday or Tuesday and so on. I am not able to get as to for each date and each hour the scan value changes, so I am confused and mixing up all here. The values for each hour on each day should be different and there is only one scan column, so how will the distinct values show up in the table.

I used the pivot table to convert the name of the week day from rows to individual columns.

Then the problem arises for ssrs report. How can this be executed in an ssrs report where the rows are for each hour and the columns displays the dates of the week selected. How can I achieve that in ssrs?  I am getting currently for only 24 hrs, but i want the report to run for all 24 hrs for 7 days and should display the value side by side for each hour in each week day column.

Thank you.

Comment: For problems like this you should post any queries you have tried, as well as table structures and sample data, as well as your expected output. Word problems are very difficult for people to get their head round, it is much easier to visualize the problem with actual data.

Comment: You will need to group on the Date's day and hour to break out the hours. For your column group, group first by the date (01/01/2017) then add a child group which groups by the Hour.

And yes, posting any query you have would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in one parameter into your stored procedure called @StartDate.

In SQL create the @EndDate like this

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = DATEADD("d",7,@StartDate)
```

Return your date information in an hour and a day column. Then use the grouping feature in ssrs to display the data.

I hope this helps you get a bit further with your issue.

Bobby

Comment: Thanks @Bobby. What I am trying to display is shown in my question above. I edited it to give a more clearer picture about my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily with a Date Dimension table and a PIVOT operator. Give that a try.